# Fecha y hora con JCalendar y enviarla a una base de datos con campo datetime

Tags: java, mysql, jcalendar

¿Como almacenar una fecha y hora con JCalendar y enviarla a una base de datos con campo datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabajando con un `JDateChooser`

```
int año = jdt.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mes = jdt.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MARCH);
int dia = jdt.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

fecha =(año+"-"+mes+"-"+dia);
```

`jdt` es el nombre del JDateChooser...

Cuando vas a guardar un tipo date la documentación dice `AÑO-MES-DIA` por eso `fecha` esta de esa manera, luego `fecha` lo pasas mediante el `INSERT INTO` igualmente como otra variable donde corresponde.

Comment: aveces la respuesta esta en solo analizar nuestro código. Me ayudo mucho tus lineas. Gracias